# Is it possible to upload file on server using scheduler or windows service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, backgroundworker

1. I am trying to do file upload using quartz job scheduler. but, it is not working.
2. Is it possible to upload file to the server using job or windows sevice.
3. I have googled but not understand much. please provide some link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upload file using windows service i guess. We build a similar kind of windows service for inserting to database recursively.[1]: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-windows-services-in-c-sharp/

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
                Fileupload();
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
                timer.Interval = 1000*60*60*10; //number in milisecinds  
                //timer.Interval = 1000 * 60;
                timer.Enabled = true;
             }
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Fileupload();
            WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
        }
```

//you can use the above 2 functions in Serivce Cs file and you define your Custom Fileupload Function for uploading file. Hope this works for you